# why does my while statement not check 2 conditions before moving on, even though there is && between both conditions?

Tags: c#

So I was trying to make a roll a dice program, where 2 dices are rolled, until both of them are equal to 6. I want my condition to check if dice and dice02 are equal to 6, before moving on, but at the moment it only checks if 1 of the dices is equal to 6 before moving on, even though Have && in the condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Random numberGen = new Random();

int roll = 0;

int roll02 = 1;
int attempts = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to roll the 2 dices");

while (roll != 6 && roll02 != 6)
{
    Console.ReadKey();


    roll = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
    roll02 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
    Console.WriteLine("You rolled a: " + roll);
    Console.WriteLine("You rolled a: " + roll02 + "\n");

    attempts++;
}


if (attempts == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It took you " + attempts + " attempt to roll 2 of a kind");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("It took you " + attempts + " attempts to roll 2 kind of kind");
}


Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With `&&` operator, second condition will be checked only if the first one is true. `&&` means both the conditions must be true, so if first one is not true there is no point checking the second condition.

Comment: The logic is flawed. Currently it keeps looking if both `roll` and `roll02` are not 6. In other words if either is 6 it breaks out of the loop. You can either use `||` or maybe a more readable alternative `while (!(roll == 6 && roll02 == 6))`

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a brief breakthrough about how your code is working:

First, it checks if the first roll doesn't equal to 6, if it does equal to 6, then it isn't satisfying the condition of both rolls not being equal to 6 and will jump away from the loop (That's really confusing, isnt it?).

To make sure that both values aren't 6 you should use the operator || so that you are iterating while either ROLL1  or ROLL2 dont equal to 6.

```
 while (roll != 6 || roll02 != 6)
    {   
        Console.ReadKey();

        
        roll = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
        roll02 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled a: " + roll);
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled a: " + roll02 + "\n");
    
        attempts++;
    }
```

As stated in the comments, there is a more legible way to do that and is with the following condition:

```
while(!(roll == 6 && roll02 == 6))
```

The operator ! is a logical "not" operator, so it will give you the reversed value of the condition that follows him. In that case, whenever both rolls are 6 its false, making it not follow the condition anymore and getting out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> even though Have && in the condition

Well that is the problem, it seems you've understood the behavior of logical operators incorrectly. `&&` is the *short-circuiting* logical AND operator. If the first condition is `false` then the second condition is never evaluated because the logical operation will always be `false`.

If you do not want the short-circuiting version of the operator, then use `&`.

That said, if you want your program to move on *only* when both dices are 6 then the logic shoul be:

```
if (dice == 6 && dice2 == 6)
   //move on
else
   //roll again
```

Here, short-circuiting actually makes sense, because you don't really care what `dice2` is if `dice` is not `6`; you are going to roll again no matter what `dice2` rolled.